# Destination host unreachable when pinging mobile in kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux

If I ping a device that is connected to Wi-Fi, It gives me error: Destination Host Unreachable.

But, If I ping a device that is connected via Ethernet through Router , then it just show me the ping… The problem is with the devices that are connected with Wi-Fi only. Like Mobile phones and laptops.

Comment: Can you ping devices in the other direction (i.e. WiFi → Ethernet)?

Comment: I cannot ping my mobile from any device wherever it is connected to wifi or ethernet

Comment: @grawity If a device is connected to ethernet, and i ping it with the device which is connected to wifi. Then it will show the ping. Problem is that i cannot ping the devices that r connected with wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like there is no route between the two. There are two scenarios why this happens:

1. The Wifi network has a different network ID and the router "forgot" to add a static route between the two networks or is configured to not add that route, which leads to my other point.
2. You have a feature like wireless isolation active, which can prevent Ethernet bound devices from accessing WiFi devices.

The gist of it is a routing issue, the solution depends on your configuration and used network devices, which you didn't mention.

Comment: SSID Isolation is off, but user Isolation is on.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I just turned off User Isolation and its working !! Thank bro, i was too frustuated from 1 week